# SSRS Group per N distinct

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to solve a problem.
As an example, let’s say I have a table containing 3 columns (Name, Timestamp, Value) with 30 unique or distinct Names and over + 1,000 rows

I have created a line chart which plots Value(Y) vs. Time(X) for each Name (series group), therefore there are 30 lines in this chart.

However, having 30 series in a chart is too cluttered and illegible for the most part. So I have placed the chart in a table (although a "List" would probably be more appropriate). I then grouped the table by "Name" which gives me one Name (series) per chart, which is great but still not ideal as this generates lots of charts and takes up many pages.

I would now like to keep the name grouping but have 5 Names (series) per chart.

I believe this is something simple but I’ve battled with this by searching and trying numerous grouping expressions for several days without any success.

Also , the order or ranking is not important.

Here is a grouping example that comes close to what I need but is not suitable as it groups per 5 lines rather than 5 per distinct name.
This expression groups per 5 lines… =Cieling(RowNumber(Nothing)/5)

Thanks

John.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to add that information on your query. If you're using SQL Server you can add to your query:

```
SELECT Name, Timestamp, Value,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name) as rownum
....
```

And then your grouping expression on the table can be `=Fields!rownum.Value Mod 5`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however this didn't work.
Firstly I needed to included the following in the SQL statement "ORDER BY" before the query would work.
Then adding the "=Fields!rownum.Value Mod 5" expression produced 5 charts with all names included in each chart. However the data in each chart looked different. I've been unable to determine why it's different or decipher any pattern between the data in each of the 5 charts.